# TCP connection using node

Tags: facebook, sockets, node.js

I would like to implement a TCP socket connection to an anonymous server{ chat.facebook.com:5222 } from a nodejs server . How / Where from do i start for this to be accomplished ?

It should be like a node replacement to fsockopen() function of PHP.

Comment: Start here http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/net.html?

Comment: Just to note, v0.4.8 is a pretty old version of Node at this point. An updated link for current documentation is http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html

Comment: That was just the first google hit :)

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I've noticed that too; I wish Google gave higher preference to newer versions. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908765/socket-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [net.Socket](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) is where you should start. *In general*, you can connect to a server like this:

```
var net = require('net');

var socket = new net.Socket();
socket.on('connect', function() {
  // socket is now connected
});
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  // socket got some data
});

socket.connect(5222, 'chat.facebook.com');
```